# Found components of potential $(x,y,z)$ - Now I need to combine

Tags: integration

I integrated the $x$, $y$, and $z$ component of Force in order to get potential.
If each component equals $-k/r$, why does the total potential also equal $-k/r$?

I would assume it would be additive, so $-3k/r$.

Can someone explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's definitely not additive. The potential is a single function (not a vector) whose partial derivatives with respect to $x$, $y$ and $z$ give the components of the force vector field. You've found that each component is indeed the corresponding derivative of $-k/r$, and that means (by definition) that $-k/r$ is the potential.